# lost space on the HDD after reinstalling windows

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, disk-space

I have a 200 Gbs HDD with vista and I decided to install Ubuntu 12.10 over it, but I found that it erased all the partitions and data and showed the file system as 198 GBs, so I tried to reinstall the windows then to recover the data but I couldn't, and after reinstalling Ubuntu and recovering some files it shows file system of only 186.3 GiBs, and some one told me that it's the same as 200 GBs

Now I totally removed Ubuntu and installed win 7, but it also shows me the partitions and the space as 186.3 GBs not GiBs with about 3 GBs missing at each partition

How can I make use of all the 200 Gbs and make windows shows the right HDD capacity???

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The minute you installed Ubuntu and then reinstalled Windows you overwrote the deleted data.  You won't be able to recover the data.  **186GB is the correct size for a partition with a filesys**tem.

Comment: i have already recovered most of the deleted data (2 out of 3 partitions), I must now have the complete capacity of the HDD

Comment: You already do.

Comment: @Nicky Windows reports in GiB - drive manufacters report in GB. It's a matter of different measurement.

Comment: so does this mean that my partition which supposed to be 44 GBs and is shown in the windows explorer as 40.8 GBs only, its real capacity is 44 GBs and it can be occupied by files and folders of 44 GBs not only 40.8 GBs ??

Answer (score 1):

You can see by `Right click` on `Computer` icon then click on `Manage`

Now goto :

> Computer Management > Storage > Disk Management

Here you can see full space of HDD, some of them is allocated and some unallocated...

Comment: all of them are allocated and it shows the disk as Disk0 Basic 186.31 GBs

Comment: 200 GB = 186.2645149230957 GiB, so nothing's missing.